# How to approach this Truck Utilisation problem?

Tags: optimization, modeling, combinatorial-optimization, r

The problem statement currently I have is very broad (or you can say very vague at the same time):

1. I have a number of dropping locations (Customer locations)
2. I have the location of the HUB
3. I have a list of available truck sizes with different rates for per kg-km and their respective fixed costs too.

Based on the historical data, I will have to model it in a way so that the total operation cost is minimized. I can select different combination of truck sizes. The main goal is to minimise the total cost.

Previously I was looking at this as a VRP with the heterogeneous fleet problem, but currently, I am feeling I'll have to model it in a different way. So far, I have reduced the number of dropping locations by clustering them and I have set a maximum demand per cluster by Capacitated clustering.

Any idea how to approach this problem? Any literature or any headway will be very helpful. I am modelling it in R, so any documentation in R will be an added bonus.

Comment: What things contribute to cost (just kg-km rates, or other things as well)? Why do you feel you need to change your approach?

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Yes, there is another cost component too, that is the fixed cost/hiring cost of the trucks. It will be more for bigger trucks and less for smaller trucks. Whereas the cost per kg per km is totally opposite.

I feel I need to change the approach because more than 'how vehicles should be routed', the question is 'how to utilise the vehicles'? This includes sub-questions like: Should small trucks be used for two shifts or one big truck be used? And few other analytical questions.

Comment: From the available truck sizes and customer quantities, would multiple customers be served in a single route? (i.e. this isn't a full truckload type problem). How does the per kg-km cost work in detail? Is it based on the total km currently on-board the vehicle? (and so it makes sense to drop-off heavier items first).

Comment: @OpenDoorLogistics yes. Multiple customers can be served in a route. Per kg-km is just an average value that has been computed based on past trips, which when multiplied with the total distance & weight carried in that trip and added with the fixed rent cost, gives approximately close to our trip cost.

Comment: @stat_shib, while you are trying to do a clustering method on your problem, you would minimize the traveling time based on kg-km. One possible way to assign/calculate the vehicle fleets is to minimize fixed cost/hiring by defining the problem (each cluster) as a generalized assignment problem that is a well-known formulation to produce a lower bound on the vehicle in use. ASAP, there are some algorithms to solve this in a reasonable time in the large-scale models. Would you try that?

Comment: @A.Omidi Thank you! I was also thinking of doing it by assignment problem. Assign the clusters to the available trucks. But one thing, there is a possibility that two clusters may be assigned to the same truck where the clusters are far apart but they satisfy the total demand constraint. Can this be avoided? Any help (with articles or journal papers) would mean a lot.

Comment: @stat_shib, one possible way would be, first, you will need to pre-calculate the worse number of vehicles that are needed for each cluster by those cumulative demands and corresponding vehicles capacity. Then partitioning the set of vehicles into the specific sub_sets based on the pre-calculating and assign each subset to the specific cluster. I hope it would be helpful.